# Default .htaccess problem in FilesMatch

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I installed Drupal 7 on a web server and can;t access the root domain.
When I comment the following lines in the .htaccess file I can load the site without any problem:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

I don't want to comment the complete FilesMatch tag as I [understand](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#filesmatch) that it protects from unwanted access to files and server resources.

What should I change?

Comment: I would check your server configuration...I have installed literally hundreds of Drupal 7 sites on a variety of different servers and every one of them has worked perfectly with the default .htaccess file

Comment: well, it is a shared hosting and the supplier claims that it is something with my .htaccess...

Comment: Yes, hosting providers do tend say things like that when they don't understand (or _want_ to understand) the problem. I have the default .htaccess in dozens of sites on various different shared hosts and they all work perfectly. The problem is definitely with your hosting provider. You can prove it easily by installing MAMP/WAMP/Acquia dev stack on your local machine, installing Drupal and confirming that you do or don't get the same error.

Comment: I did. it is working great on XAMPP

Comment: I think you have your answer then...your hosting provider isn't providing you with even the most basic server configuration settings. The only advice anyone can really give is to convince your hosting provider to change their over-arching .htaccess policy (unlikely in my experience), or move to someone who offers a full service.

Comment: It might be worth adding the name of your hosting provider to the question; someone else may have used them and know of a way to get around the server limitations

Answer (score 1):

if you use one.com

I just find out, that you can remove or commenting

```
Options -IndexesOptions 
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

in the htaccess file, and then it should work. I don't know why.